# What is an exact definition of a snapshot on Solana

Tags: ledger, snapshot

There is a lot of disjoint info about snapshots, say [here](https://docs.solana.com/proposals/snapshot-verification), or [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/wiki/Incremental-Snapshots) and even [here](https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder). However, I do not completely understand what snapshots are and how can they be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these refer to the same family of snapshot actually: An **accounts database snapshot**.

### What's inside?

A snapshot is a compressed tar archive (`.tar.bz2`, `.tar.gz`, `.tar.xz` or `.tar.zst` file) containing the following data:

- A dump of Solana accounts (pubkey, owner, SOL balance, data, etc) in the *AppendVec* file format. This is the same format that the accounts database uses.
- The bank state: Metadata about the implicit state of the chain when the snapshot was taken (network stakes, etc)

Each snapshot targets a specific slot number and uses a cryptographic hash value that uniquely identifies the data stored within the snapshot.

### Full vs incremental snapshots

There are further two types of snapshots that differ in the amount of data they store:

- Full snapshots contain all accounts at a specific slot

  ```
  snapshot-139240745-D17vR2iksG5RoLMfTX7i5NwSsr4VpbybuX1eqzesQfu2.tar.zst
  ```
- Incremental snapshots contain all accounts *that changed* between a specific slot and a specific previous snapshot

  ```
  incremental-snapshot-100-200-AvFf9oS8A8U78HdjT9YG2sTTThLHJZmhaMn2g8vkWYnr.tar.zst
  ```

### Uses of snapshots

Solana nodes load snapshots on startup to start syncing at a recent block height instead of having to execute the entire blockchain history from genesis.

Currently validators delete their accounts database and start from a snapshot even if their account data is recent. Naturally nodes automatically generate full and incremental snapshots while they are running to ensure they can start up again.

When a new node joins the network for the first time, it loads a snapshot from a trusted provider (e.g. another node you operate or a slot where the accounts hash has been agreed on by stake supermajority).

Additionally, snapshots are useful for analytics purposes to quickly load a collection of accounts.